# SASS/SCSS sourcemap on sharepoint framework webpack

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, sharepoint-framework, webpack

Is there any way load the sass/scss file as the sourceMap in dev mode? I understand that sharepoint framework is using webpack which transpiles all sass/scss files into css then render it within the `<style>` element. However it becomes a bit painful if the project gets bigger and when I will need to locate a certain rule.

I have had a look around on some articles:
https://ihaveabackup.net/article/sass-with-sourcemaps-webpack-and-live-reload

And tried to apply the suggested changes as follows, but it still referencing the css to  instead of the scss file.

```
build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({ 
  additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => { 
    generatedConfiguration.module.loaders.push(
        [{
          test: /\.scss$/,
          loaders: [ 'style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap' ]
        }]
    ); 
    return generatedConfiguration; 
  } 
});
```

Comment: changes are done in gulpfile.js